# How to see all partitions on an SSD

Tags: usb, partitions, usb-on-the-go

I have an SSD with 2 partitions (volumes? ) on it. I can R/W to both of them from my WIN10 PC. 
However, when I mount it on my Note10 , I can only see one of the partitions. 
Is there a way that I can see both partitions when I open file manager?

Comment: What file-systems are used by the partitions?

Comment: It depends on multiple factors including if `vold` supports multiple portable partitions on portable storage, if `voldmanaged` entry in `fstab` for your USB OTG storage device is configured to recognize multiple partitions, if partition type (id set while creating partition table) is supported by `vold` etc. With root access however you can handle things manually. You can check kernel log and `logcat` to see if both partitions are recognized when attached.

Comment: you need custom ROM because stock ROM only mounts first partition